# Usable charset for Moldava

Tags: character-encoding

Does anybody knows which charset is used in Moldava. We to prepare our software (and database) for Moldava. I guess UTF-8 should work, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-8 works for everything :-)

The question is whether your software will need to interface with "native" applications. If so, it may need to understand the encodings used by that software. Those are most likely [ISO-8859-5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-5) for cyrillic script and [ISO-8859-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-16) for latin script.

Answer (score 2):

Moldova has some controversy on what script to use (Transnistria uses [Moldovan Cyrillic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moldovan_Cyrillic_alphabet) and mainland uses latin with lots of diacritics).

UTF-8 is always a good choice, anyway.